# BlueWallet: How to find channels infos

Tags: lightning-network

I setup a LN wallet with BlueWallet. Then I use a faucet (https://lightningnetworkstores.com/faucet) to get 6 SAT.
In BlueWallet I can see I'm connected to lndhub.io

My question: Where are the channel's infos ?
To open a channel, there must be a tx in the blockchain !

Also: is there a way to see the invoice of the ln tx ?

Answer (score 0):

In their website bluewallets' lightning experience is described as:

> You can use our hosted Lightning wallets or connect to your own node.

#### Channel

So, if you don't have your own (I guess LND only) Lightning node, I guess you are using a custodial wallet, so your balance is just a database entry behind the balance of a large lightning node controlled by bluewallet team. Your deposit transaction probably did not cause a channel to be opened, but it's just an incoming LN transaction to the bluewallet node which uses their available incoming liquidity.

#### Invoice

The faucet you linked uses [LNurl withdraw](https://docs.lnpay.co/api/lnurl-withdraw/how-does-lnurl-withdraw-work) to send money. This means that your wallet decoded the lnurl string or QRcode, getting something like `https://lightningnetworkstores.com/api/lnurl2?id=C9yU9yPVHW37783hoaDABd`. Your wallet then proceeded to send a get request to that url, which returned some info and a callback URL. Finally your wallet generated an invoice (through the central bluewallet node) and sent it to the server (via callback URL) to be paid.

However I have no clue whether or where you can find invoices in bluewallet.